# Zero set of complete vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $X$ be a complete smooth vector field. I know that if $X$ has periodic integral curves, then it can vanish somewhere, e.g. take the coordinate vector field of the polar angle on the plane.
My question is the following:

Is it possible for the zero set of $X$ to be non-empty if all its integral curves non-compact, i.e. diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?
I think that it can not be the case, and would be thankful for some confirmation.

EDIT: Changed a misleading word

Comment: If $X(p) = 0$, the integral curve through $p$ is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$...?

Comment: My confusion probably comes from the idea that there could be curves that have zero velocity at some point but still continue, e.g. $\gamma(t) = t^3$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see: That's can't happen because a smooth vector field is locally Lipschitz, so the flow equation ODE has unique solutions.